# Change HTML5 video source when using Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, video, html5-video, blob

How to link my function `changeVideoSource` to my video tag? I retrieve video data from mySQL and I want to display the video, I am using Java Spring Boot.

```
<body> 
<div class="jumbotron col-xs-12" th:each="film: ${films}"> 
<p th:text="${film.titre}"/> 
<video id="video" width="200" height="200" th:onloadstart="changeVideoSource(${film.filmvideo}, this.id)" controls>
</video> 
</div> 
</body> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function changeVideoSource(blob, videoElement)
{  
    var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); 
    console.log(Changing video source to blob URL "${blobUrl}"); 
    videoElement.src = blobUrl; 
    videoElement.play(); 
}

</script>
```

Comment: Code in an image is not testable. You need to [use edit to paste your code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64943738/edit) into your question. During editing, select the code text and then press the button `{ }` and that will convert text into a code block.

Comment: @VC.One I tried it but it does not convert all my text

Comment: Paste all the text in there again and I'll fix it for you

Comment: <div class="jumbotron col-xs-12"  th:each="film: ${films}">

     
     
    
    <p th:text="${film.titre}"/>    
<video id="video" width="200" height="200" th:onloadstart="changeVideoSource(${film.filmvideo}, this.id)"  controls></video>

    
    
   
    
    
    
   
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeVideoSource(blob, videoElement) {
   var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   console.log(`Changing video source to blob URL "${blobUrl}"`);
   videoElement.src = blobUrl;
   videoElement.play();
 }



</script>

Comment: I don't use Spring Boot but while you wait for an answer, see if mine helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification:

```
<div class="jumbotron col-xs-12" th:each="film: ${films}"> 
<p th:text="${film.titre}"  />

<video id="myVideoTag" width="200" height="200" controls> </video>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

///# setup the vars
var myVid = document.getElementById( "myVideoTag" );
var myBlob = ${film.filmvideo};

//# run the function
myFunc( myBlob, myVid )

function myFunc( videoElement)
{  
    console.log( "videoElement is : " + videoElement );
    var blobUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob); 
    console.log(Changing video source to blob URL "${blobUrl}"); 
    videoElement.src = blobUrl; 
    videoElement.play();
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you , but how to use this js function in the HTML video tag , onloadstart ? is not working...I am retrieving blob data from mysql database

Comment: I'm confused. What is the purpose of `onloadstart` in your code? The computer will read your code from top to bottom, so when it reaches the JS code part, it can just change the `.src` of the previously created video tag. I can't test your `${blobUrl}` but hopefully the edit helps you.

Comment: Thank you for the attention give to my question, may be I am not clear , my question is : when you retrieve a file (BLOB) from a database and you want use this file as a video .<video src="...">, this src is supposed be a string value , now my question is when it's blob value , how we can process it ? I see many eg in google but they still not reply my question. I tried to do it in js with this function who with an event onload ...i am in final year school engeeniring

Comment: _"when it's blob value , how we can process it ?"_ That's what `.createObjectURL(blob)` is doing. It creates an internal string path to the blob as if it was a file. Make sure your Blob is of actual video data (meaning if you saved your blob as file bytes on disk then that same file can now be opened by a media player or browser). PS: Did you test the code since it was edited? Make sure your blob has MP4 data for best compatibility. If still failing to work then save a test video blob as file and share download link here for testing.